# each , functions and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several elements and I want a function to get the width and offset of each element when I do click. I want to save both values of each element so I can access to it from outside the function and do stuffs. I tried this code but im stuck. thx.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("div>div").off("click").click(function() {   
      var checkWidth ;
   var checkLeft ;
   function checkPosition() {    
     $("div>div").each(function() {
          checkWidth = $(this).width();
       checkLeft = $(this).offset().left;
        });   
        return [checkWidth, checkLeft];
   }
  var test = checkPosition() 
  alert(test);        
 });
 
 // if( width of second element is # && offset of third element is # ) {
 // do some thing ;
  ¨ //  }
 
})
```

```css
div div{
    position: relative;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;  
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.rectangle1{ 
 background-color: black;
 width: 100px;
 left: 10px;
}
.rectangle2{
 background-color: red;
 width: 200px;
 left: 30px;
} 
.rectangle3{ 
 background-color: black;
 left: 60px;
 width: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>  
    <div class="rectangle1"></div>
    <div class="rectangle2"></div>
    <div class="rectangle3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean "stuck"? What's wrong?

Comment: @DavidS , it means I started but I could not finished it, its incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define array out of function to make it global and also use each(index) to properly set the values of array:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myarray=[];
    $("div>div").off("click").click(function() {        
        var checkWidth ;
        var checkLeft ;
      function checkPosition() {          
        $("div>div").each(function(index) {
          checkWidth = $(this).width();
          checkLeft = $(this).offset().left;
          myarray[index]=[checkWidth,checkLeft];
        });         
        return myarray;
      }
     var test = checkPosition() 
     alert(test);                   
    });

    //if( width of second element is # && offset of third element is # ) {}
    // if (myarray[1][0]==130 && myarray[2][1]==120){}
    // as you have a two dimensional array and javascript array starts from 0:
    // myarray[n][0] will return the width of n+1(th) element
    // myarray[n][1] will return the offset of n+1(th) element
    

})
```

```css
div div{
    position: relative;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;  
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.rectangle1{ 
 background-color: black;
 width: 100px;
 left: 10px;
}
.rectangle2{
 background-color: red;
 width: 200px;
 left: 30px;
} 
.rectangle3{ 
 background-color: black;
 left: 60px;
 width: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>  
    <div class="rectangle1"></div>
    <div class="rectangle2"></div>
    <div class="rectangle3"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: how can I pick the values of the array and use them in the if statement that is commented at the bottom of the script?

Comment: I added the method of retrieving data as javascript comment in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle for the answer. Check it here  https://jsfiddle.net/dj2jdzrp/

```
    var divProperties;
    $("#outerDiv > div").click(function(e) { 
    divProperties = {"offset" : $(this).offset() , "width" : $(this).width() }
    alert('anchor clicked!'+ divProperties.offset.left + 'width'+         divProperties.width); 
    });
```

Comment: I want  the values of all the elements and save them some where( array) so later I can pick the values i want and use them  in the if statement (at the bottom of the code)